# Umbraco 6.05 on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-storage

I am deploying Umbraco 6.05 to Windows Azure. I am currently using "Azure Web Sites" to do this, but from what I can glean, it appears that this may cause future problems with the storage of media being on the local file system (both due to space limitations and also due to scaling considerations). The site was created and uploaded using WebMatrix.

I have found various articles about using Blob Storage for this, but they all refer to "Cloud Services" and "Web Roles" - none of which seem to match with the current terminology used on Azure, and to be totally honest I am not that familiar with Azure yet anyway. I have also found various "accelerators" for previous versions but nothing for this version.

Can anybody provide any links to a definitive guide to the installation of this version of Umbraco as an Azure Web Site, utilising Azure Blob Storage where appropriate? If this is not feasible, perhaps further advice can be provided as to the recommended way of hosting Umbraco in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

There are no different in term of how they store the file whether you use Web Sites or Cloud Services as long as you didn't modify the Umbraco.

Both Web Sites and Cloud Services keep the file, in this case, the Media folder in their local storage unless you modify Umbraco to save into Blob Storage to have a better scaling.

You can write and modify your own custom Media location or try to look at this URL http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/universal-media-picker

Comment: `as long as you didn't modify the Umbraco` - that defeats the main purpose anyone uses a CMS for. Umbraco i still pretty 'old school' in that even if you provide it a SQL database, it writes some changes to the local disk :/ ... which means those changes are not durable across role recycles (worse, if you have N roles, only 1 role's local disk sees those changes!). The OP is looking for a way to redirect those disk-writes to something like Azure Blob.